# SpriteKit & Swift: Nodes not colliding even though their collisionBitMask's are correctly set up

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-physics

Im making a 2D sidescroller game. I have a character named dragon and various platforms, obstacles & enemies etc coming from right to left. My character collides with the platforms but not with the obstacles. I've tried to make him collide with the obstacles but somehow it does not work.

**Setting up categoryBitMasks:**

```
    struct PhysicsCatagory{
static let dragon : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
static let ground : UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
static let platforms : UInt32 = 0x1 << 3
static let bigGroundPlatform : UInt32 = 0x1 << 4
static let enemy : UInt32 = 0x1 << 5
static let obstacle : UInt32 = 0x1 << 6
static let obstacleDeathObject : UInt32 = 0x1 << 7
static let spring : UInt32 = 0x1 << 8
}
```

**Here's how i set up my character:**

```
func addDragon() {

    dragon = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Dragon-Standing")
    dragon.zPosition = 100
    dragon.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.6, 0.5)
    dragon.position = CGPoint(x: 300, y: 300)
    dragon.setScale(0.21)
    dragon.name = "Dragon"

    let dragonsPhysicsBody = SKSpriteNode()
    dragonsPhysicsBody.size = CGSize(width: 170, height: 170)
    dragonsPhysicsBody.zPosition = 99
    dragonsPhysicsBody.position.x = dragon.position.x; dragonsPhysicsBody.position.y = dragon.position.y

    dragon.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: dragonsPhysicsBody.size)
    dragon.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.dragon
    dragon.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.ground | PhysicsCatagory.platforms | PhysicsCatagory.bigGroundPlatform | PhysicsCatagory.obstacle
    dragon.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.ground | PhysicsCatagory.obstacle
    dragon.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    dragon.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    dragon.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    dragon.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
    dragon.physicsBody?.mass = 0.176455050706863


    worldNode.addChild(dragon)

}
```

**Code for the Obstacles:**

```
    func createObstacle() {

    if imageNameObstacles == "Stone_Obstacle1" {

        wasStoneObstacle1Here = true
        wasStoneObstacle2Here = false

        obstacle = SKSpriteNode(texture: stone_Obstacle1_Texture)
        obstacle.xScale = 0.32
        obstacle.yScale = 0.27
        obstacle.zPosition = 3


        let randomObstaclePositions = arc4random_uniform(3) + 1;
        // RANDOM OBSTACLE POSITION STUFF

        obstacle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: obstacle.size)
        obstacle.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.obstacle
        obstacle.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.dragon
        obstacle.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.dragon
        obstacle.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        obstacle.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        obstacle.physicsBody?.friction = 0.0
        obstacle.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.0

        groundPair.addChild(obstacle)
    }
```

**Code for my Platforms:**

```
    func platforms_3() {

    spawnedPlatform3 = true

    bigGroundPlatform = SKSpriteNode(texture: middle_Ground_Platform_Texture)
    bigGroundPlatform.zPosition = 4
    bigGroundPlatform.xScale = 0.45; bigGroundPlatform.yScale = 0.50
    bigGroundPlatform.position = CGPoint(x: 2800, y: 355)

    bigGroundPlatform.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: bigGroundPlatform.size)
    bigGroundPlatform.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.bigGroundPlatform
    bigGroundPlatform.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.dragon
    bigGroundPlatform.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    bigGroundPlatform.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    bigGroundPlatform.physicsBody?.friction = 0.0
    bigGroundPlatform.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.0

    groundPair = SKNode()
    groundPair.zPosition = 4

    groundPair.addChild(bigGroundPlatform)


    let movePlatforms = SKAction.runBlock({
        () in

        let distance = CGFloat(25000)
        let moveGroundObjects = SKAction.moveByX(-distance, y: 0, duration: NSTimeInterval(self.platformSpeed))
        let removeGroundObjects = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        self.moveAndRemove = SKAction.sequence([moveGroundObjects, removeGroundObjects])

        self.groundPair.runAction(self.moveAndRemove)
    })

    groundPair.runAction(movePlatforms)
    worldNode.addChild(groundPair)

}
```

The collisionBitMask's for my platforms are not set up because if my character was under a platform and tried to jump he would collide with it instead of jumping through it and then landing on it. 
**This code resolves the above mentioned issue:**

```
    func makePlatformsNil() { // Runs in update function

    if dragon.physicsBody?.velocity.dy < -0.0 {

        platform1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.dragon
        platform2.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.dragon
        platform3.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.dragon
        platform4.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.dragon
        platform5.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.dragon
        platform6.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.dragon
        platform7.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.dragon
        platform8.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.dragon
        platform9.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.dragon
        platform10.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.dragon
        bigGroundPlatform.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.dragon
        bigGroundPlatform2.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.dragon
        dragon.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.ground | PhysicsCatagory.platforms | PhysicsCatagory.bigGroundPlatform
    }

    if dragon.physicsBody?.velocity.dy > 0.0 {

        platform1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        platform2.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        platform3.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        platform4.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        platform5.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        platform6.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        platform7.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        platform8.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        platform9.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        platform10.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        bigGroundPlatform.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        bigGroundPlatform2.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        dragon.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.ground
    }

    if collidingWithGround == true {
        bigGroundPlatform.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        dragon.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.ground
    }
}
```

As you can see the both collisionBitMask's of my dragon and my obstacles are correctly set up but their still not colliding. Does someone now why? 
I've put a print statement in didBeginContact to see if its being called when dragon and obstacle are colliding, it is being called.

Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: from what I am seeing, your dragon only collides with ground, platforms, and bigGroundPlatform

Comment: yikes, that is not a good way to handle jump, you should not have to change the platforms like that, you should be changing it during your didBeginContact test, and only changing the platform that is being touched, and you should be changing the platform category, not the platform collission bit mask

Comment: @Knight0fDragon How do you mean that it only collides with ground and platforms? Am i seeing it wrong or what is happening here, because what i see is that in the collisionBitMask of the dragon is obstacle defined and vice versa. And for the platforms, i now what you mean and i did like you said before, but the problem with that was that if the dragon was falling and on his way to land on a platform he would sink in the platform a little bit and then get pushed up again. My guess was that didBeginContact has a little delay in it, thats why i did it wit the update function instead and it worked

Comment: you are changing it `dragon.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.ground`, and didBeginContact has no delay

Comment: because your dynamic is false, the collisionBitMask will not work on platform hit sprite,  so the only outcome is sprite hit platform

Comment: @Knight0fDragon dang it, you are right! I completely over saw that i was changing it in `func makePlatformsnil()` I changed it and now they collide, thank you. If didBeginContact has no delay in it how do you explain that weird sink in behavior?

Comment: not sure to be honest

Comment: it is possible that the push back could take a few frames,  the contact mask tells you where the sprite made a contact point, so it is very easy to just move the sprite up on didbegincontact

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Alright, im gonna test that now and report the outcome. Thank you :-)

Comment: I don't have enough REP to comment but do you have `self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self` in your didMove function??